# Raspberry pi with ubuntu: Forwarding all traffic from one interface to another

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, iptables, forwarding

I have two Raspberry Pis running Ubuntu. Both of them have a native ethernet port and a usb ethernet->usb interface. They are both connected with their native ethernet to the same home router.

I want them to forward all traffic from their usb interfaces through a GRETAP interface that tunnels with the physical eth0 interface to the other Pi. The tunnel is up and running but i need to find a way to make traffic from the usb interfaces to go through the tunnel. This is to create a two way ip-tunnel, sort of.

I'll try to illustrate with a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLXta.png

What is the easiest solution? Is this possible with something like iptables? Can i set the tunnel as a default gateway?

Comment: The short answer would be "yes, but". Could you please clarify your question a little? Do you literally mean that *all* traffic coming in from eth0 will be automatically forwarded to usb0 in both boxes and vice versa, without the RasPi taking any other action on the packets? Why exactly, what do you want to achieve? Please don't answer as a comment, but update your question. Please include the IP addressing scheme you plan to use, each system, each interface. The more details you give, the better the answer can be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i realize i left out some important stuff. I edited the question, hopefully it's better now.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit clearer, but I'm still confused. I think that's because you also are :-) A tunnel is created between the end points, so your RasPis can create a tunnel between each other. That tunnel would pass through the eth ports and the router. But they see the USB and Eth interfaces as their own network interfaces - there you can't have a tunnel. To explain better I'd need to expand this to an actual answer, which I don't want to do with this information. So again, please show the endpoints, add your proposed IP addressing scheme for all devices and interfaces. The more details etc.

Comment: Also please, what is the "router"? Is it an actual router, or is it an ISP router or similar? That's important, because actual routers forward traffic differently than ISP-provided home routers.

Comment: Thank you! Yes i might be a bit confused haha! 

Ok added some IPs and maybe a clearer view of the setup. The router is a home router like you would find at the store kind of.

Comment: Alright, now it starts to make sense :-D You didn't include subnet masks, so I assume the usual 255.255.255.0. The eth0 interfaces are in the same subnet, which means the "router" isn't actually routing that traffic - it's switched. In which case tunnel between those interfaces makes really no sense. Also the 192.168.10.x addresses make sense here only if that's the IP addressing you intend to use in the tunnel- that correct? There starts to be enough info that I can chew this a bit and give you some pointers but only on general, abstract level.

Comment: Nice! Sorry if it is all a bit messy.

Yes the submask for all of them is 255.255.255.0. And yes, the 192.168.10.x addresses are only for tunneling (and are picked at random honestly). 

Since the goal is basically just to take non-IP traffic from outside (the clouds in the image), send it over the tunnel to encapsulate in IP, then send it out from the other device as the original, non-ip, protocol - is the router not doing anything here? Can i just connect them directly to each other with ethernet cables? 

The router is in the system only to give me easy access with SSH to the pis.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I lost the convo, found it back today. I realized I had forgotten how GRE actually worksd so had to read up, and build a test lab... I should know, but it's a decade and a half since I've dealt with it...

Answer (score 0):

All routing is based on destination, which must be either an IP address or an interface. I.e. either `"send all traffic with destination address a.b.c.d to e.f.g.h"` or `"send all traffic with destination address a.b.c.d out from interface X"`. It's not possible to create a rule `"send all traffic received from interface A to interface B"`.

There might be an application that can be run on the OS to monitor the interfaces and just forward all usb1 incoming traffic to eth0; and vice versa. I'm not aware of any.

For practical purposes there's no point in creating a tunnel between the RasPis; same result can be achieved without. Tunnels are used to cross multiple routing interfaces. RasPi A and B have eth0 interfaces in the same 192.168.1.0/24 -net - the traffic between these interfaces is not routed, it's switched; i.e. forwarded using the MAC addressing. Just as an exercise on GRE routing it makes sense.

The IP addressing in the topology will not work. This is because the RasPis themselves are acting as routers. As soon as an interface has an IP address, it has a direct interface into that IP range; and direct path is always prioritized over a routed path.

In the picture RasPi A:s interfaces have IP addresses 192.168.10.3/24 and 192.168.1.104/24. It will forward all traffic addressed to network 192.168.10.0/24 out from usb1.

RasPi B:s interface IPs are 192.168.10.2/24 and 192.168.1.102/24. It will forward all traffic addressed to network 192.168.10.0/24 out from usb2.

Therefore: RasPi A can't be configured to send traffic to 192.168.10.0/24-network so that it would reach RasPi B:s usb2 (except as a backup route in case of failure, which defeats the purpose). And vice versa. Tunneling will not change this. The only way around to change one of the IP ranges; for example change RasPi2 usb2 IP to 192.168.11.2/24.

Changing the IP range we can create routes that allow networks 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24 to communicate:

```
RasPi A: 192.168.11.0/24 => 192.168.1.102
RasPi B: 192.168.10.0/24 => 192.168.1.104
```

All traffic directed to net 192.168.11.0/24 RasPi A receives from any interface will now be forwarded to RasPi B:s eth0 interface; and vice versa.

Now we can also create the tunnel:

```
RasPi A: 
Tunnel source eth0/192.168.1.104
Tunnel destination 192.168.1.102
Tun0 IP 172.10.0.2/24

RasPi B:
Tunnel source eth0/192.168.1.102
Tunnel destination 192.168.1.104
Tun0 IP 172.10.0.1/24
```

We can direct the routes between 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24 to the tun0 interfaces just by replacing destinations:

```
RasPi A: 192.168.11.0/24 => 172.10.0.1
Raspi B: 192.168.10.0/24 => 172.10.0.2
```

All traffic directed to net 192.168.11.0/24 RasPi A receives from any interface will now be forwarded to RasPi B:s tun0 interface; and vice versa.

Device-specific routes are done exactly the same way. For example if usb2 connects to a device with IP 192.168.11.10 we just need to change the network's address .0 to device address .11.

If both USBs actually connect to other routing devices, 192.168.10.1/24 and 192.168.11.1/24, we can do this:

```
RasPi A: 
192.168.10.0/24 => 192.168.10.1
0.0.0.0/0 => 172.10.0.1

RasPi B: 
192.168.10.0/24 => 172.10.0.2
0.0.0.0/0 => 192.168.11.1
```

0.0.0.0/0 (Default Route) stands for unknown networks; i.e. any IP for which the router doesn't have a more specific route. 0.0.0.0/0 must be pointing to the next-hop router.

With this configuration all traffic destined to 192.168.10.0/24 will be forwarded to 192.168.10.1. All traffic *not* destined to 192.168.1.0/24 or 192.168.10.0/24 will be forwarded out to 192.168.11.1 connected to usb2.

For obvious reasons it's not possible to create on both RasPis a default route that would point to the other. Inbound traffic would reach each RasPi, but go nowhere further.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I appreciate it! 

Will try this out as soon as i can, things have changed on my end since i posted this on my end! :) 

I'll let you know, but it seems like this is solid! 

Thanks again, best regards.

Comment: Cool! I was sort of concerned; some ppl with some knowledge may take offense when one starts explaining basics :-D If you have questions about it please feel free :-)